# Why does my Visual Basic program just quit? It stops executing within one minute of start-up

Tags: vb.net

On **some** computers my VB program just quits with no warning or indication why it did so.    And it does so within a minute of start-up.    It’s as if there is a one-minute time limit.   You can fire it up again and the same thing happens.  It happens at the login screen, at the home screen, at other screens.  It happens when no code is executing. It’s happening on Windows 10 computers and possibly on earlier versions.  On most computers it runs without a problem.  I’m at a loss as to why this is happening or what I can do to fix it.   Has anyone else experienced this problem?   Does anyone have any suggestions for fixing?

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what the program is doing or seeing some code

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour]. Feel free to post some specific code and we'll see if we can help you. Have you looked to see if you're getting .net errors in the event log? Do you have an application level error handler?

Comment: A wild guess: Some uncaught exception in a thread other than the main thread?

Comment: checking the event viewer for the log would help get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.   It really s hard to know.  And I don't think code is involved because it happens no matter where in the set of programs that you are.  You can click to start up and it can sit at the login screen.  It will quit after a minute.  Go to some other screen; it will quit after a minute.  We have an application event handler but it does not catch what is happening here.  I will check the event viewer and event log.  Thanks for these suggestions.  We did disable virus protection but that did not help.  Thank you and I'll try to get more information.

Comment: I'm hoping to have a solution to this in the next couple of days; a good friend and techie is going to look into it.   If I find out the answer I'll definitely post it here.    Thanks.

Comment: I want to close this because I don't think the answer will be found.   But, I don't see where I can close this.   I'll keep looking.  Thanks.